# Add button on TYPO3 backend list view

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I need to add button on TYPO3 backend list view (here for example):
[image: typo3 backend list view]

Purpose of this button is similar to hidden button, I want to change flag Top News from 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1.

I have no idea where to start, I found how hidden button working but I have no clue how to add own button and work with it. If possible, please add any links to extension, which have solution for that problem, or code which solved that or anything else will be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['typo3/class.db_list_extra.inc']['actions']`hook.

[This way](https://bitbucket.org/blueways/bw_bookingmanager/src/development/Classes/Hooks/EntryRecordListHook.php) I added a custom toggle button and controlled the display of other buttons via TypoScript.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you :)